# Can a Muslim cook pork?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, pork

If someone asks for my help to cook something that has pork, can I help this person? I'm not going to eat, just going to help cook the food.

Comment: I would suggest you gently decline this if you can. Also I have seen couple of your posts. My humble opinion is it is more important to know the virtues of righteous actions (Fadaail) and doing them than having knowledge of issues (Masaail). The more you do righteous actions, the more you will become enlightened and will gain deeper understanding of the Masaail. This is my opinion but you may disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Eating pork is Haram in Islam and helping in a sin is prohibited in the holy Quran:

> ...وَتَعَاوَنُوا عَلَى الْبِرِّ‌ وَالتَّقْوَىٰ ۖ وَلَا تَعَاوَنُوا
>   عَلَى الْإِثْمِ وَالْعُدْوَانِ ۚ وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ ۖ إِنَّ اللَّهَ
>   شَدِيدُ الْعِقَابِ
>
> ... And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but **do not cooperate in
>   sin and aggression**. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is severe in
>   penalty.
>   http://tanzil.net/#5:2

Comment: So what's the word is it permissible or not? Please directly state that in the answer.

Comment: @BleedingFingers is not prohibited same as not permissible?

Comment: It is. But you should point out if cooking pork is helping in sin and why is it so, that way the answer will be complete, unambiguous and will definitely stand out.

Comment: Eating pork is a sin for muslims, ok. But it isn't a sin for christians or people from other religions.

Comment: @MFS it is sin for all. there is only one religion: http://tanzil.net/#3:19

Comment: -1, it isn't a sin for non muslims which I am confident is what the OP asks for.

Answer (score -1):

It should be fine as long as you don't eat it and the person that is going to get it is not forbidden for them.

However, if for example you married a Christian/Jewish woman who drinks wine or eats pork, it is not allowed to buy/serve the Alcohol as stated in many [hadiths](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/6):

> لَعَنَ اللَّهُ الْخَمْرَ وَشَارِبَهَا وَسَاقِيَهَا وَبَائِعَهَا وَمُبْتَاعَهَا وَعَاصِرَهَا وَمُعْتَصِرَهَا وَحَامِلَهَا وَالْمَحْمُولَةَ إِلَيْهِ ‏
>
> Allah has cursed wine, its drinker, its server, its seller, its buyer, its presser, the one for whom it is pressed, the one who conveys it, and the one to whom it is conveyed

However, there is no hadith about those who serve pork, only [forbiddance](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/99) in selling it. In your case I don't see anything from the Sunnah or Qur'an that prohibits it.

Answer (score -3):

No, we can't even cook it because our this act helps other to perform sin. In simple words our this act helps others to go against Islam.